# Agora.io remote video is blank. only audio works. Everything in local works

Tags: java, android, agora.io

have spent the past 15 hrs trying to find a way to fix it, but sadly haven't found one, any help will be appreciated.

```
Extra info: local video n audio works, even remote audio. But not remote video.


Stracktrace:
```

spoiler!!. the stacktrace is very big!!!!

```java
05/27 22:56:36: Launching 'REmote_ctrl.app.Slave' on Wingtech 2014818.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.satyamedh.slave/com.satyamedh.slave.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 6721 on device 'wingtech-2014818-192.168.1.21:5555'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
```

rest in https://pastebin.com/GvB64q5t

ask me any code and I will edit the body.

edit:one of the two activities:

```java
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import io.agora.rtc.Constants;
import io.agora.rtc.IRtcEngineEventHandler;
import io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine;
import io.agora.rtc.video.VideoCanvas;
import io.agora.rtc.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration;
```

........ rest in https://pastebin.com/UDf2inMJ

Comment: Have you checked the camera permissions?

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code? It's much harder to debug what went wrong without that.

Comment: @SamyakJain, yes I have asked for the perms

Comment: @ShaochengYang there, edited the post

Comment: There's a credential leakage in your pastebin. I can see your app id. I'd recommend you to take that out.

Comment: @SamyakJain, oops. I don't have a acct. I can't edit it. Anyway. what happens? I can delete the project n start a new one!. easy. but pls help me with the error

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes to the UI, you need to make sure to do it on the UI thread. In your case, you're calling the `setupRemoteVideo()` method. You need to make sure to do it inside the UI thread. Here's how you would do that:

```
@Override 
public void onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded(final int uid, int width, int height, int elapsed) { 
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            setupRemoteVideo(uid);
        }
    }); 
}
```

You can take a look at this sample app as well for your reference: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/blob/5a1433db49010f07e08b52f8f7913381c727b3a5/One-to-One-Video/Agora-Android-Tutorial-1to1/app/src/main/java/io/agora/tutorials1v1vcall/VideoChatViewActivity.java#L98

Comment: I will try in 5 mins!

Comment: ping, plz help. I want to finish it by the end of the month

Comment: from you code it looks like you are using your own surface view. I'd recommend you do it the way, the sample app has done. Create something like a framelayout for your remote view container. Create a surfaceview using this method: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a85e696124a3e608b82f71e323cdc1aef. And add the created surfaceview as a child of the remote container. I highly recommend you take a look at the sample app that I linked in my answer and try to emulate that.

Comment: yes @SamyakJain. I just havent tried it out. will do it tom if I have time

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself (in iOS). For us, it was that we set up the canvas uid with *our* `uid`, but it should be the remote user’s `uid`. You can use that if you have it when you first set up the engine, or you can wait till you get the `didJoinedOfUid` or `remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid` callbacks to set it.